# Open GL timing with drawFrame thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rotation, translation

I have a 3D world that works well with a camera and game objects. When the camera 'renders' it positions the matrix in the location of the camera. To do this, I call the following code:

```
gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationArray,0);
gl.glTranslatef(position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());
```

Now when each object gets rendered, I call this for each object. (Note that I push and pop the matrices appropriately)

```
gl.glTranslatef(position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());
gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationArray,0);
```

Now my question comes into play of when I bring models into the world, I need certain Meshes to pivot not around the 0,0,0 point, but around a different point. I have an object called Mesh that has an ArrayList of submeshes. Each mesh (and submesh) have a pivot point location. (an x,y and z float).

Where do I translate the matricies so I pivot around the designated point? I've tried all sorts of combinations and nothing works!

Example:

```
gl.glTranslatef(position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());                     
gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationArray,0);
gl.glTranslatef(pivotPoint.getX(),pivotPoint.getY(),pivotPoint.getZ());
```

and I've tried

```
gl.glTranslatef(pivotPoint.getX(),pivotPoint.getY(),pivotPoint.getZ());                     
gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationArray,0);
gl.glTranslatef(position.getX(), position.getY(), position.getZ());
```

Comment: What does this have to do with timing or threads? In any case, what you want to do to rotate the object around an arbitrary point is to translate the object to the origin first, then rotate and translate back to the original position. In your case, however, you do not want the origin to be (0,0,0), so translate by -(pivotPoint), rotate, translate by +(pivotPoint).

Comment: Oh no, did I include a thread tag? Where is it? I was working on a previous one that I didn't finish that had to do with threads, but yeah, this shouldn't have to do with threads.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thank you! That was the trick! If you write an answer I'll up vote it and accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to rotation around an arbitrary point. Traditionally when you rotate an object, you usually rotate it around the object's center but in this case you have a separate pivot point.

The process of rotating an object around any arbitrary point is:

1. Translate by -(RotationPoint)
2. Rotate
3. Translate by +(RotationPoint)